# Positioning text over a set of images using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to place the names of employees over their portrait.

I'm looping through an object of objects to get the employees by hire year

```
var classes = { 
2013: { 
"image/path.png" : "name of employee", 
"image/path2.png" : "name of employee2" 
}, 
2012... 
}
```

And am looping through them with jQuery `each` to display their portraits and names by hire year:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            //identify all elements in <li>
            $('li').on('mouseover', function(e){
                $('#overlay').empty();
                var title = $('<h2>');
                title.text('Class of ' +  e.target.id);
                $('#overlay').append(title);

                $.each(classes[e.target.id], function(path, name) {
                    var img = $('<img/>');
                    img.attr('src', path);
                    $('#overlay').append("<span class='imagesContainer'>");
                    $('#overlay').append(img);
                    $('#overlay').append("<span class='names'>" + name + "</span>");
                    $('#overlay').append("</span>");
                }); 
            });
        });
```

To get their names to appear over their respective portraits, I've followed this [this](http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/) guide and tried encasing the images in a position: relative container (`$('#overlay').append("<span class='imagesContainer'>"); ... append image here ... $('#overlay').append("</span>");`, then placing the text over it by positioning: absolute... but it doesn't work...

CSS:

```
        #overlay {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;

        }
        .imagesContainer {
            position: relative;
            float: left;        
        }

        .names {
            position: absolute;
            /*background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);*/
            padding: 5px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        }
```

Any thoughts how I can get each name to appear over the correct image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append()` doesn't work that way. You can only append full elements, not just pieces of them. So you need to create `.imagesContainer`, append the other elements to that, then append the `.imagesContainer` to `#overlay`:

```
var $imgContainer = $("<span class='imagesContainer'>");
$imgContainer.append(img);
$imgContainer.append("<span class='names'>" + name + "</span>");

$('#overlay').append($imgContainer);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew where I wanted to go, but didn't know `append()` didn't allow partial appending. I was using that technique all the time with PHP. Quick question, why do you need to set the `imgContainer` variable to a jQuery variable `$imgContainer`? What's the difference? Does making it a jQuery object allow you to access its properties, such as `append()`?

Comment: Appending to the DOM is a relatively expensive task. You could append the `.imagesContainer` to `#overlay` first, then append the two items to that, but that would modify the DOM three times. The way I've done it only modifies the DOM once.

Comment: Okay, just for clarity... Can you explain a little more how yours only modifies it once? I'd like to understand this so I can optimize how I develop things in the future... thanks!

Comment: Sure. The first line creates an element, but that element is detached, the document hasn't been modified. It's not until the last line that I actually modify the document by appending elements to it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, "_to a jQuery variable $imgContainer_". Prepending a variable name with a `$` is just a convention to make it easy to see that the variable contains a jquery object instead of a native DOM element. I could have named it anything.

Comment: Okay thanks so much. Last question: There are two issues: 1) The script works in Chrome, but if I keep hovering over the classes, occasionally some images do not appear... 2) In IE8, the images do not show at all, only the title "Class of..." appears.

Comment: That could be any number of things. Are you using jQuery 2.x? That doesn't support IE8. If not, it could be any quirk of IE8 including css issues.

Comment: It's not a jQuery issue. It was working in a script before when I was using arrays to store the image paths per year (ex: `2013: [ path1, path2, etc ], 2014: [ ...`).  But I don't think the data structure has anything to do with it either. Since then, I've only added the CSS that you see above... So I don't think it's a CSS error either. Now for IE8, it's saying there is an error on the page... error is: `'console' is undefined on Home.aspx`, and `'length; is null or not an object` in my jquery file...  Btw, this is a javascript function I've added to a SharePoint page.

Comment: `'console' is undefined` makes me think there is a line trying to log to the console `console.log(something)`, which IE8 may not support. I'm not sure on the other error, but I don't think anything I can see here is the cause of that.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you are using jQuery 2.x, some things may work in IE8, and others may not. The behavior is unpredictable.